# Where is the 'ViewLocator' or 'WebformViewLocator' in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm looking at some (old) sample projects of ASP.NET MVC 2, to do some self-teaching on the subject.

However, I 'WebformViewLocator' no longer seems to be present in MVC2, while it is used in the sample projects...

Searching for breaking changes on WebFormViewLocator does not make me any smarter...

Has it been removed/replaced/renamed?

Comment: Which (old) sample project are you talking about? Url please.

Comment: A multi tenancy POC, can be found at http://code.google.com/p/winecellarmanager/downloads/list (MultitenancyPOC.rar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see these classes in the first check-in of the code on Codeplex:

View Locator
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/590#8302

Web Form View Locator
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/590#8310

But they were not present in RC1 but if you check out classes such as ViewResult, is has its own FindView method.

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/21528#266531